# Array shuffle repeating values

Tags: php

I have this code that make a query on a table and then do an insert in another insert a field with random integer value, but it is repeating when I have many records.

Code:

```
$d = connection::select(select * from tabela1);

    foreach ($d as $reg) {

        $c1 = $reg['c1'];
        $c2 = $reg['c2'];
        $c3 = $reg['c3'];

        $count = count($reg);

        $numbers = range(1, $count- 1);
        srand((float) microtime() * 10000000);
        shuffle($numbers);
        foreach ($numbers as $number) {

        }

        connection::exec("insert into table2 (c1,c2,c3,seq)values('$c1','$c2','$c3',$number)");
}
```

Comment: summing array..

Comment: If you think about what your code does it's quite logical it repeats. You have to redo it to actually get what you're trying to do. And not use empty for loops in it

Comment: Don't call `srand()` each time through the loop. Call it once at the beginning of the script.

Comment: @Barmar.. The result is the same. I tried to delete the srand (). But it did not change the result

Comment: That's just a general recommendation, not related to the problem you're having. See my answer for the real solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create the array of random numbers outside the main `foreach` loop. Then just use one element of the array for each insert. This way you won't ever get any duplicates.

```
$d = connection::select("select * from tabela1");
$rows = $d->fetchAll();
$count = count($rows);
$numbers = range(1, $count);
srand((float) microtime() * 10000000);
shuffle($numbers);
foreach ($rows as $i => $reg) {
    $number = $numbers[$i];
    $c1 = $reg['c1'];
    $c2 = $reg['c2'];
    $c3 = $reg['c3'];
    connection::exec("insert into table2 (c1,c2,c3,seq)values('$c1','$c2','$c3',$number)");
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. How do I count without PDO, this error occurred `Notice: Undefined offset´

Comment: What is `$d`? I assumed it was an array, since you use `foreach($d)`.

Comment: You're using your own database connection class, don't you know how to use it to get the information you need, like the number of rows? In PDO it's `$stmt->rowCount()`, in mysqli it's `mysqli_num_rows()`.

Comment: I found that the problem is in fetchAll, the loop does not work if you have $rows = $d-> fetchAll (); $Count = count($rows); If you assign a value to $count, it works normally. @Barmar, know any function to replace the fetchAll?

Comment: I can't think of any reason why `fetchAll()` wouldn't work. You're using PDO, right?

Comment: I believe so, I auditioned repeating a query, it worked.

Comment: What value do you get for `$count` when you use `$count = count($rows);`?

Comment: empty, I had to exchange for $ rows = $ d->fetchAll ();
                    $Count = count($rows);

Comment: What is `$d`? I assumed it was the result of calling `fetchAll()` in your `connection` class.

Comment: $d is the variable that will be the query, I have to produce the array, but it seems that after fechtAll, the clean php memory and lets not run the loop. I'll post my class connection.

Comment: `fetchALL()` retrieves everything from the query into a 2-dimensional array. You should be able to count it, and should be able to use `foreach()` on it as in my updated answer.